# Run 2 Python servers simultaneously and process received data

Tags: python, server

I have 2 Python servers which are cyclically receiving data from 2 different sensor systems. Both servers are running fine individually.

I would now like to run both servers simultaneously and process the received data together in one application which receives the data from one of the servers and then requests the data from the other server. However, I currently have no approach how I could implement this in an efficient way.

Does anyone here have an approach, a similar problem or an idea how this could be implemented efficiently?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You should look into Apache beam. It can deal with batch and streaming data.

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with IOT system, i think you should use mqtt broker